How do I capture the two-finger tap event on status bar?
I'm building a mac app with status bar icon. I want to enable two-finger tap guesture when tapping on the icon (note: physically, you tap the touchpad). Tried the following code, but even if I use
button.sendAction(on: .any), handleTwoFingerTap is not triggered.
class StatusBar {
  var statusBar: NSStatusBar!
  var statusBarItem: NSStatusItem!

  init() {
    statusBar = NSStatusBar()
    statusBarItem = statusBar.statusItem(
      withLength: NSStatusItem.variableLength
    )
    if let button = statusBarItem.button {
      // code to set up icon is ignored

      // Doesn't work
      button.sendAction(on: .any)
      button.action = #selector(handleTwoFingerTap(_:))
      button.target = self
    }
  }

    @objc private func handleTwoFingerTap(_: Any?) {
      // this function is not called
    }
}

I suspect this is due to the limitation of sendAction, quote

The only conditions that are actually checked are associated with the NSLeftMouseDownMask, NSLeftMouseUpMask, NSLeftMouseDraggedMask, and NSPeriodicMask bits.

In that case, how to make this work?

This doesn't make sense to me. How do you "tap" on the status bar with "two fingers" no less? MacBook screens are not touch screens.

Does two-finger tap on a trackpad do the same as right-click with a mouse?

@Sweeper I meat tap the touch pad not screen.

@Willeke it's different. PopClip has this feature, if tap with two fingers it will toggle app's status (on/off), if right or left click, it opens the menu.

Turn PopClip On and Off: "As a short-cut, you can also toggle PopClip on and off by secondary clicking (Right-click or Control-click) the PopClip icon in the menu bar.". Mac Trackpad gestures: "Secondary click (right-click): Click or tap with two fingers.".

Have you tried NSGestureRecognizer?
